# Why don't my PHP_EOL line feeds break as they should?

Tags: php

I have viewed numerous posts on this subject but they have not resolved my issue. In addition to PHP_EOL, I have tried $lf = "\n", but still no line feeds.

PHP

```
    $lf = PHP_EOL;       
    $bodyText = str_replace('</div>', $lf, $wheading . $body);
    $bodyText = strip_tags(str_replace('</p>', $lf, $bodyText));
    $bodyText = strip_tags(str_replace('<br/>', $lf, $bodyText));
    $signature .= '<a contenteditable="false" target = "_blank" href="' . 'mailto: ' . $edata['Email'] . '?subject=Reply from: ' . $wdata['Name'] . ' to: ' . $edata['Name'] . 
                  "&body=<<" . PHP_EOL . $bodyText . $lf . '>>"' . '>Email us</a>';
    if ($edata['Phone']) $signature .= '<div>' . $edata['Phone'] . '</div>';
    $signature .= '<br/><p>Please do not reply to this email</p>';
    $buttons = "</div><div id='buttons'>";
    echo $heading . $body . $signature;
```

OUTPUT

> <<Ron TornambeRonald Tornambe, Inc.134 Padova WayVenice, FL
>   34275Hello: We are interested in reviewing your novel entitled Moby
>   Dick.If the address you posted on the Writer's Tryst website is
>   correct, we will send our standard forms and manuscript submission
>   instructions to you there. If not, please send us your preferred snail
>   mail address using our email address shown below. Thank you for
>   considering the Lynette White Literary Agency.>>

What am I missing?

Comment: You might want [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert new lines to `<br>` HTML elements.

Comment: ^ HTML email expects .. HTML. Just like browsers email clients looking at HTML will ignore line breaks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I am using "mailto" as my email client and it does not accept HTML

Comment: welcome to the 20th century, no one likes mailto. best to use a form and a mailing script.

Comment: ok a 5 secounf search: "You should use a carriage return %0D and line feed %0A"

Comment: I guess you missed it, but it is now the 21st century. All kidding aside, I resorted to mailto because the email link will be within an email, so a form is out of the question. I'll try the %OD %OA and let you know how it goes.

Comment: No that didn't work at all.

Comment: since a mailto is still an url, you should probably run `$bodyText` through `urlencode`. in fact, everything that is not a fieldname like `body`

Comment: That did it. Please provide an answer so I can reward your good work.